# Analogy of a Fano manifold with anticanonical divisor

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry, fano-varieties

Some people say that a Fano manifold with anticanonical divisor is an analogue of a manifold with boundary. Where does this intuition come from?

Comment: Simplest example of a Fano: $\mathbb{P}^1$, and $-K_{\mathbb{P}^1} \cong 2p$. Not really an example of manifold with boundary.

Comment: In a sense, a complex manifold with a divisor is an analogue (or a "complexification") of a real manifold with boundary.

Comment: @Enrico Consider (the closure of) one connected component of $\mathbb{RP}^1 \setminus \{0,\infty\}$. That's the manifold with boundary that $\mathbb P^1$ is supposed to be _analogous_, not equal, to.

Answer (score 3):

I'd say it's closer to an oriented manifold with corners (corners happening where the divisor is singular), or even that times a coefficient. In [these papers](https://arxiv.org/search/advanced?advanced=&terms-0-operator=AND&terms-0-term=rosly&terms-0-field=author&terms-1-operator=AND&terms-1-term=polar+homology&terms-1-field=all&classification-mathematics=y&classification-physics_archives=all&classification-include_cross_list=include&date-filter_by=all_dates&date-year=&date-from_date=&date-to_date=&date-date_type=submitted_date&abstracts=show&size=50&order=-announced_date_first) Khesin, Rosly, and later Thomas build a homology theory based on this analogy.